# SSDT Intellisense not even an option

Tags: visual-studio-2019, intellisense, sql-server-data-tools

I'm using VS2019 and SSDT. [This blog](http://www.dotnetspeak.com/ssdt/ssdt-intellisense-not-working/) shows how to turn on Intellisense for SSDT. However, I don't have that option. Any ideas?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

For VS2019, it exists under **Tools**-->**Options**-->**Text Editor**->**SQL Server Tools**-->**Intellisense**

[image]

I have that option. I think you're looking in the wrong place. Please follow my path to use that option.

Comment: Thanks for the guidance. Weirdly, mine looks just like yours, but I don't get Intellisense at all in the editor. Maybe I'm missing how it's supposed to work. For example, when I'm editing the .sql of a stored procedure, and I type "select * from customer where customer." I'd expect a list of column names to come up after the dot - not correct?